# Docker-compose: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a problem trying to run my flask, python, celery, mongodb and rabbitmq app via docker.

When I run the docker build command and then compose-up
I get the following problem:

[image]

The problem appears to be when running the command: docker-compose up.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine AS builder

RUN pip install poetry

WORKDIR /backend

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install --no-root

FROM python:3.11-alpine

WORKDIR /backend

COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/bin/

COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=/
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq

  celery_worker:
    build: .
    container_name: celery_worker
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://admin:admin@rabbitmq:5672
    restart: always
    command: celery --app src.task worker --loglevel=info -O fair --queues default 
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq

  flask_app:
    build: .
    container_name: flask_app
    command: python3 src/app.py
    restart: always
    tty: true
    environment:
      - SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - SERVER_PORT=5000
      - FLASK_APP=src/app.py
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq
      - celery_worker
volumes:
  mongodb_data:  # Volume para persistência dos dados do MongoDB
  rabbitmq_data: # Volume para persistência dos dados do RabbitMQ
```

The folders structure:

[image]

src/app.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from src.task import add

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    add.delay(1, 2)
    return "Docker compose working!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = os.environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    port = os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '8001')
    print(f"Server listenning {host}:{port}")
    app.run(host=host, port=port, debug=True)
```

src/task.py:

```
import os 
from celery import Celery

broker = os.environ.get('CELERY_BROKER_URL', 'amqp://guest@localhost//')
celery = Celery('myapp', include=['src.task'])

@celery.task(queue='default')
def add(x, y):
    print(f'Adding {x} + {y}')
    return x + y
```

pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = ""
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ""

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
Flask = "^3.0.0"
celery = "^5.3.6"
pymongo = "^4.6.1"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

i can't perform the up using docker-compose up
because of the errors, this is the exact code and folder structure I currently have. Can anyone tell me how to fix this and if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
from src.task import add
```

by

```
from task import add
```

The file task is in the samne directory than app